# Prove there is no the continous function $g:[a,b]\to \{a,b \}$ such that $g(a)=a, g(b)=b$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Prove there is no the continous function $g:[a,b]\to \{a,b \}$ such that $g(a)=a, g(b)=b$.

Using properties of connected and proposition that any continuous function $f:[a,b]\to [a.b]$ has fixed point.

Can you help me? Any hint will be appreacite.

Comment: Hint: the image of any continuous function defined on a connected space is connected.

Comment: I would say the intermediate value theorem is the best fit for this problem. Also, you might want to specify that $a\neq b$, or even $a<b$.

Answer (score 2):

The image of a connected set by a continuous map is connected. $[a,b]$ is connected, but not is $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: $\{a,b\}$ could be connected

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: Let $s:\{a,b\} \to [a,b]$ be given by $s(a) = b, s(b)=a$. Then $s$ is continuous and if $g$ existed, $s\circ g$ would be a fixed point free function on $[a,b]$. Contradiction.